# Move commits into another branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have made three commits to master branch and pushed them to remote. The changes should have been minor (applying a bugfix release of a framework), but ran into really big trouble and should therefor have gone into a different branch until the problems are sorted out and can be merged back into the master branch.

Is there a way to move these commits retroactively into a newly created branch and get them out of master branch?

No one has checked out the changes yet, but I expect them to do soon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a new branch *bug-fix* that contains the commits, i.e., where branch *master* currently is:

```
git checkout -b bug-fix master
```

This assumes that you have not yet added even more commits on top of the bad ones on branch *master*. This command also moves you away from branch *master* because we need this precondition in the next step.
Now rewind the *master* branch locally:

```
git branch -f master bug-fix~3
```

Finally, push it out to the remote:

```
git push origin +master
```

All the caveats of rewritten and published history apply, of course.